# Powershell Regex for optional equal sign separator in string

Tags: powershell, regex-group

In the Test String below there could either be **an equal sign** OR **one or more space characters** between the Key and the Value. If the equal sign is present it may be optionally preceded and/or succeeded by zero or more space characters.

```
$MyTstString = "KeyX =  ValueY"
$RegExString = "^(?<Key>.+)(?<Sep>\s*=\s*)(?<Value>.*)$"
$MyTstString -match $RegExString | Foreach {$Matches}
```

What regular expression would do that for me?

Changing the RegExString to

```
$RegExString = "^(?<Key>.+)(?<Sep>\s*=\s*|\s+)(?<Value>.*)$"
```

causes the Key and Sep to be incorrect when the TestString is "KeyA  = ValueB"

Comment: I can't answer your regex question, but `-match` returns `$true` or `$false`. You'll want to remove the pipe, and put the `foreach` on the next line like: `$Matches | Foreach-Object { ... }`

Comment: -match also populates the $Matches hashtable, and the ForEach after the pipe prints out each element of the $Matches hashtable, so yes I could put the $Matches | ForEach on a new line, but it would not affect how the -match is actually using the $RegExString. That's the part I need help with. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the foreach won't iterate over every match this way, which is what it looks like you're trying to do. Sure, you can foreach over the returned boolean as you are, which will run once, and then print `$Matches` but it's a really odd way of doing this and doesn't capture your coding intent very well to others who may need to maintain your code in the future.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see your point about "coding intent" earlier. Will modify my code accordingly.

Comment: The answer has settled down now, in a manner of speaking. It now uses a simplified separator subexpression and also explains the problem with your original regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: `\s` matches *all forms* of whitespace, not just *spaces*, including tabs, newlines, ... To limit matching to just spaces, use a  verbatim space ( ) in lieu of `\s` below.

---

I suggest **using a [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operation combined with a *multi-assignment*** instead:

```sh
$key, $value = $MyTstString -split '\s*=\s*|\s+', 2
```

<sup>Note: The `, 2` part (specifying the optional [`<Max-strings>` operand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split#max-substrings)) ensures that only at most *two* tokens are returned; otherwise, the value part could end up *itself* get split up if it happens to contain whitespace or `=`. Thanks, [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron).</sup>

If you also want to capture the separator string:

```
$key, $sep, $value = $MyTstString -split '(\s*=\s*|\s+)', 2
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

As [Bender the Greatest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584676/bender-the-greatest) points out, a [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operation with a *scalar* LHS:

- *returns* `$true` or `$false` to indicate if the regex matched.
- if it did match, populates [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) with the - one - match it found (it never goes looking for more).

(By contrast, with an *array* (collection) as the LHS, `-match` returns the (potentially empty) *sub-array of matching elements*, and does *not* populate `$Matches`.)

**Using your original approach**, with a corrected and streamlined form of your regex:

- The **problem with your regex** (both variations) is that **`(?<Key>.+)` is *too greedy*** and includes *spaces before `=` or the last space* in the capture-group match.
- The simplest solution is to simply **make the `+` quantifier *non-greedy***: `(?<Key>.+?)`; alternatively, limit the matched characters to *everything but whitespace and `=`*:
  `(?<Key>[^\s=]+)`.

```
$RegExString = '^(?<Key>.+?)(?<Sep>\s*=\s*|\s+)(?<Value>.*)$'

'KeyX1 =  ValueY1', 'KeyX2 ValueY2', 'KeyX3=ValueY3' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match $RegExString) {
      [pscustomobject] @{ Key = $Matches.Key; Sep = $Matches.Sep; Value = $Matches.Value}
    }
  }
```

The above yields:

```
Key   Sep  Value
---   ---  -----
KeyX1  =   ValueY1
KeyX2      ValueY2
KeyX3 =    ValueY3
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you - Bender, Cpt.Whale and of course mkelement0 - You folks are the greatest! Not only did you help me solve my problem, but I learnt a little bit more about -match returning a boolean and its side effects on the $matches hashtable, the concept of greedy searches and the non-greedy quantifier.